# Changing Database Owner Removed User Mapping

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I ran an ALTER AUTHORIZATION to change a database owner from an AD account to sa and it seemed to cause the user mapping for a specific database to be removed. I’m not sure why this happened.

Is this normal and expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database owner is mapped to the `dbo` user in the database, so when you change the database owner, you change which login is mapped to the `dbo` user.

The previous database owner may loose access to the database.

eg

```
use master
drop database mydatabase
go
create database mydatabase
go
use mydatabase
go
select sid
from sys.database_principals 
where principal_id = 1
go
alter authorization on database::mydatabase to sa
go
select sid
from sys.database_principals 
where principal_id = 1
```

outputs

```
sid
-------------------
0x0105000000000005. . . 

(1 row affected)

sid
-------------------
0x01

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains it!

Comment: @stephen Great that it solved your question, could you accept the answer so that it is clear for future readers? [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is some more information on accepting answers.